# Checking whether Raster has Attribute Table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, raster-attribute-table

I can't seem to find a Describe property or any tool that will tell me whether a raster has an attribute table.

I can do it with a simple try/except statement on a test cursor or a table-specific tool, but those return relatively generic RuntimeError and ExecuteError, respectively. That seems messy and insufficient.

Is there a property/tool that will give me a simple boolean indicating whether the raster has an attribute table?

*It's not that I want to ensure that there is one; it's that I simply want to test whether there is one.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you seek is this:

```py
import arcpy
my_raster_layer = arcpy.Raster("dem")
if my_raster_layer.hasRAT:
     print "Has a VAT!"
else:
     print "No VAT!"
```

For some reason they have decided to call it a RAT despite years of calling a VAT...

Comment: Thanks, so much! I will probably stick with the try/except, since it takes a while to initialize the Raster object, but this may come in handy in the future.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that property. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

If it is important to you to always have a VAT you can use the [Build Raster Attribute Table (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#/Build_Raster_Attribute_Table/0017000000m2000000/) tool with the overwrite set to NONE (this is the default). That way if there is no VAT it will create a basic one and if one exists it will leave it alone (or update as specified by you).

Note: this will not work for rasters of type "32-bit floating point". But you could test for that with [Get Raster Properties (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#/Get_Raster_Properties/0017000000m7000000/)

Comment: Thanks, jb. But, it's not that I want to build one if it's not there. It's that I want to know whether I can proceed with some analysis. In this particular case, I don't have write access to the database containing the rasters, so if it doesn't have a RAT, I'll skip it.